# Bug Cookie: laravel_session in owasp zap

Tags: laravel, session, cookies, laravel-session

I used OWASP ZAP software which enable you to test your website in attacking it , it finds security failures. So I did it to my Laravel Application 5.4 version and I have this error[image]

[image]

To be honest I don't really understand what I have to do to fix that cookie laravel_session problem, if some one can help me, give me some advice, it could be nice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, it's weird but when I disabled my debugbar in laravel, the errors disappeard in owasp zap software.